# How to fetch data of html form fields using jquery ajax from daabase

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

Let's have a example:
file.html

```
<input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname">
<input type="text" name="txtemail" id="txtemail">
<input type="text" name="txtaddress" id="txtaddress">
```

now file.php

```
assume connection already done and the variable $con.
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name, email, address from users where id='$userid'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry);
$txtname= $row['name'];
$txtemail = $row['email'];
$txtaddress = $row['address'];
```

Now i don't want to write any single code of php in the html file let it be pure hmtl. also do not want to write any html code in php file let it be pure php.

is there any secure (minimum) way to put the results of php files in respective form field of the html file using jquery ajax???

may be it is a stupid question. But i want to with clarification as i am learning now. i do not want to use PDO and OOPS as i don't know.

Comment: Please explain in detail.

Comment: It is ok to write php code in html, there is no other option to populate the php variables into the form field.

Comment: @shreyas dharav if you don't know please don't make users confused, afraid. It's useless & harmful also.... Special thans to Kittu

Comment: I apologize for the second part of my statement as I completely forgot the 'ajax'. but php way is not useless & harmful, rather it will be much safer than the ajax as ajax can be exploited to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes using Ajax its possible.
First In php file echo out your result like below

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

and then you can write below code in html file in script tag and populate fields accordingly

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {          
            $('#txtname').val(data.name)
            $('#txtemail').val(data.email)
            $('#txtaddress').val(data.address)

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanl you so much @Kittu i love innovation & innovative peoples.

Comment: It my pleasure @DhrubajyotiSen :)